# Dash to Dock stopped working after update (Ubuntu 21.10)

Tags: dash-to-dock

I upgraded to 21.10 a week ago and was pleased to find "Dash to Dock" was working in the new Gnome version 40.

Then this morning I got a notification that there was an update for "Dash to Dock" available. I accepted the update and got an ERROR message. I went to  https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/ and have tried installing versions 69, 70 and 71 under Gnome 3.38,40 and 41 but all leave me with the ERROR message and no "Dash to Dock"

Comment: Did you try to restart GNOME or logging out and back in (after installing dash-to-dock for GNOME 40)?

Comment: That worked! Write it as an answer and I'll mark it as the solution. Thank you!

Comment: This worked but, we cant keep doing it always. Please disable the default Ubuntu-dock, if using Dash-to-dock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, for the extension updates to work, a GNOME restart is needed.

If you are not using Wayland you can quickly restart GNOME by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, entering `r`, pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

If you are using Wayland you can log out of your current the GNOME session and log back in.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same issue, but once I disable built-in "Ubuntu-Dock", in the extensions, everything seems to be fixed.